# A stochastic integral computed using Itô's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I need some help with this question:

I have to check the following "identity" using Itô's lemma, but I can't see how to do it...

$$\bullet\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s}W(r)\;drds=-tW(t)+(t+1)\int_{0}^{t}W(s)\;ds$$

($W(t)$ is the Wiener process)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Edit: The "identity" finally was not true (as saz and Did proved)

Comment: In addition to two already good answers, i want to add if the result of this type holds, it should be attainable by a substitution argument, because your BM only appears in the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "identity" does **not** hold: Obviously,

$$t \mapsto \int_0^t \int_0^s W(r) \, dr \, ds$$

and

$$t \mapsto (t+1) \cdot \int_0^t W(s) \, ds$$

are both differentiable (for fixed $\omega \in \Omega$). In contrast,

$$t \mapsto t \cdot W_t$$

is almost surely nowhere differentiable. This means that the equality

$$\int_0^t \int_0^s W(r) \, dr \, ds - (t+1) \cdot \int_0^t W(s) \, ds = - t \cdot W_t$$

cannot hold.

Comment: I think using the word "identity" was too strong for my part.

This exercise is proposed in my lecture notes after having proved that $\int_{0}^{t}y\;dW(y)=tW(t)-\int_{0}^{t}W(y)\;dy$ (applying Itô's lemma to $dX(t)=dW(t)$ with $f(t,x)=tx$) to show that we must simulate $W(t)$ to compute values of  $\int_{0}^{t}y\;dW(y)$.

The hint of this exercise suggests to use a similar resoning to prove it. If it's not an equality, could at least be a "distributional equality" or something? Maybe the notes are wrong. But if we apply what you say, the previous exercise that I mentioned is wrong too...

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman No, the previous one is not wrong, because the stochastic integral $$\int_0^t y \, dW(y)$$ is not differentiable (in $t$). I have to think about the "distributional equality"...

Comment: Thi s is a very interesting approach!

Answer (score 2):

Itô's lemma is quite irrelevant here (note there is no stochastic integral in the identity you suggest) and, as already mentioned by @saz, the identity cannot hold pointwisely because the LHS is a $C^1$ function of $t$ while the RHS is not. If only *distributions* are concerned, note that both sides are centered gaussian hence their distributions coincide if and only if their variances do.

The LHS $X$ is 
$$
X=\int_0^t(t-s)W(s)\;\mathrm ds,
$$ and $E[W(s)W(u)]=\min(s,u)$ hence
$$
\mathrm{var}(X)=2\int_0^t(t-s)\int_0^s(t-u)u\;\mathrm du\;\mathrm ds=\frac{t^5}{20}.
$$
Likewise, the RHS $Y$ has variance
$$
\mathrm{var}(Y)=t^3-2t(t+1)\int_0^ts\;\mathrm ds+2(t+1)^2\int_0^t\int_0^su\;\mathrm du\;\mathrm ds=\frac{(t^2-t+1)t^3}3.
$$
Thus, the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ do not coincide.

Comment: Is it that obvious that both sides are Gaussian? (Actually, as the variances do not coincide, the distributions cannot coincide; it doesn't matter if they are Gaussian or not.)

Comment: @saz Both sides are normal as limits of linear combinations of normal families. // It would matter that both sies are normal if the variances were equal.

Comment: Nice approach, Did!